# how can this possibly be possibly lost memory? valgrind

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks, heap-memory, valgrind

I use valgrind to detect memory lost, and I know that possibly lost should be treated as definitely lost, however, I have this very simple program, and how can it possibly lose memory? I do not randomly allocate any pointer in the middle of nowhere..

First, I write a function to create a fresh string of arbitrary size: (allocate memory, then set all the values in the array to 0, end it with a 0. this is as clean as it could be, in my opinion.)

```
#include <stdlib.h>

char    *ft_strnew(size_t size)
{
    char    *str;
    size_t  i;

    str = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (size + 1));
    if (str == NULL)
        return (str);
    i = 0;
    while (i < size)
    str[i++] = '\0';
    str[i] = '\0';
    return (str);
}
```

Then I use this function

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *ft_strnew(size_t size);

int main()
{
    char *s;
    s = ft_strnew(2);
    s[0] = 'a';
    s[1] = 'b';
    s[2] = 0;
    free(s);
    return 0;
}
```

If I don't `free(s)` valgrind says I definitely lose 3 bytes. Now it put `free(s)` and valgrind says I definitely lose 0 byte.

1. However, it always says I possibly lose 72 bytes. What does it mean? How to fix it?
2. At the end of the report, it says 2 errors, what are those errors?
3. How to fix the 'still reachable'? Is it important?

```
➜  libft git:(master) ✗ valgrind --leak-check=full ./a.out
==28757== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==28757== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==28757== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==28757== Command: ./a.out
==28757==
--28757-- run: /usr/bin/dsymutil "./a.out"
warning: no debug symbols in executable (-arch x86_64)
==28757== Syscall param msg->desc.port.name points to uninitialised byte(s)
==28757==    at 0x1003AA34A: mach_msg_trap (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib)
==28757==    by 0x1003A9796: mach_msg (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib)
==28757==    by 0x1003A3485: task_set_special_port (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib)
==28757==    by 0x10053F10E: _os_trace_create_debug_control_port (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib)
==28757==    by 0x10053F458: _libtrace_init (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib)
==28757==    by 0x1000A89DF: libSystem_initializer (in /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib)
==28757==    by 0x100018A1A: 
ImageLoaderMachO::doModInitFunctions(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==28757==    by 0x100018C1D: 
ImageLoaderMachO::doInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==28757==    by 0x1000144A9: ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, char const*, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==28757==    by 0x100014440: ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, char const*, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==28757==    by 0x100013523: ImageLoader::processInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==28757==    by 0x1000135B8: ImageLoader::runInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==28757==  Address 0x10488bd6c is on thread 1's stack
==28757==  in frame #2, created by task_set_special_port (???:)
==28757==
==28757==
==28757== HEAP SUMMARY:
==28757==     in use at exit: 18,207 bytes in 162 blocks
==28757==   total heap usage: 179 allocs, 17 frees, 24,354 bytes allocated
==28757==
==28757== 72 bytes in 3 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 26 of 42
==28757==    at 0x10009A0B2: calloc (in /Users/lnguyen/.brew/Cellar/valgrind/3.13.0/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==28757==    by 0x1005B3832: map_images_nolock (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==28757==    by 0x1005C6D6A: map_images (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==28757==    by 0x10000803B: dyld::notifyBatchPartial(dyld_image_states, bool, char const* (*)(dyld_image_states, unsigned int, dyld_image_info const*), bool, bool) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==28757==    by 0x100008255: dyld::registerObjCNotifiers(void (*)(unsigned int, char const* const*, mach_header const* const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*)) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==28757==    by 0x10020100A: _dyld_objc_notify_register (in /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib)
==28757==    by 0x1005B3072: _objc_init (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==28757==    by 0x10019468D: _os_object_init (in /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib)
==28757==    by 0x10019463A: libdispatch_init (in /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib)
==28757==    by 0x1000A89D5: libSystem_initializer (in /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib)
==28757==    by 0x100018A1A: ImageLoaderMachO::doModInitFunctions(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==28757==    by 0x100018C1D: ImageLoaderMachO::doInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==28757==
==28757== LEAK SUMMARY:
==28757==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==28757==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==28757==      possibly lost: 72 bytes in 3 blocks
==28757==    still reachable: 200 bytes in 6 blocks
==28757==         suppressed: 17,935 bytes in 153 blocks
==28757== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==28757== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==28757==
==28757== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==28757== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==28757== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 12 from 12)
```

Comment: thank you i was trying to edit the error report

Comment: It seems that your valgrind output does not match your code. It seems that your real program is a C++ program, which uses the `ImageLoader` class and many more.

Comment: weird. i put the function in `ft_strnew.c`, i put the main in `main.c` and i do this: `gcc main.c ft_strnew.c` and then i `valgrind --leak-check=yes ./a.out`

Comment: Delete the `a.out` file and try again. It seems to be a complete different program.

Comment: It reported no errors for me: `All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible`.

Comment: still reachable blocks shouldn't be considered as leaks

Comment: weird. i delete `a.out`, i put them in new directory and compile again.. still.......

Comment: regarding: `str = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (size + 1));` 1) the expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined in the C standard as 1.  Multiplying anything by 1 has absolutely no effect.  Suggest removing that expression.  2) the returned type from the heap allocation functions: `malloc` `calloc` `realloc` is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting the returned value just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc. Suggest removing that cast.

Comment: regarding: `if (str == NULL)
        return (str);`  When the call to `malloc()` fails, a NULL pointer is returned to `main()`.  `main()` starts writing to that pointer.  When `malloc()` fails, this will result in a seg fault event.  Suggest using: `if (str == NULL) {  perror( "malloc failed" );  exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }`

Comment: Suggest replacing the call to `malloc()` with a call to `calloc()` and removing these statements: `while (i < size)
    str[i++] = '\0';
    str[i] = '\0';`

Comment: regarding: ` i = 0;
    while (i < size)`  Strongly suggest replacing with: `for( size_t i =0; i < size; i++ )

Comment: the error report says: `179 allocs, 17 frees,`  but the posted code only shows 1 alloc and 1 free.  Please correct the posted code or replace the error report with the real one,

Comment: thank you for all the added information. this code is written with the norm in my school. also, people say that i run this on mac so there is something messing with `valgrind` and the possibly lost memory report is not due to my program